# Same javascript file in different MVC bundles

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Does it make sense to put the same file in two different bundles? If you look below I have the file recentOrders.js in two different bundles because in one request I need the first one but in a different request I need only the second. Is this used frequently or is there a better way to solve this type of problem?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/order").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/topCalendar.js", 
                    "~/Scripts/order.js",
                    "~/Scripts/recentOrders.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/recentOrders").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/recentOrders.js"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would, if different "sections" of your site don't need a specified script. Even if a specified section doesn't need a script inside the bundle, it wouldn't be bad to include it for the sake of maintainability/simplicity. However, If you're going down the path of optimizing your site, creating separate bundles for specific sections of your site would be an approach to increase the site's responsiveness/load times.